# How do you sketch a signal given by x(t) = A(t/T) for time period 0 to T? Does t/T simply denote that the signal covers entire T duration?

Tags: math, signals, signal-processing, waveform, wave

Does t/T simply mean that the signal has magnitude A over the entire "T" duration? Or does it mean that it covers only a fraction? How will it look?

Comment: I suggest you try with a concrete signal and actual numbers for t and T. For example you could take a signal A that covers a duration of 5sec, and choose T=10. Then plug in values of t=0,1,2,... and see what happens.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it stands this question isn't really about programming or software algorithm and as such isn't [on-topic for stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).